# Display JSON data in Marathi language using PHP web service

Tags: php, json

I have a PHP web service in which I am retrieving data from mysql database. In database the data is stored in Marathi language, but when I am running my web service in postman, data is coming but many question mark symbol are displayed. How to solve this issue? Below is my PHP web service code:

```
<?php

//include config_db.php
include_once('config_db.php');

$qr = "SELECT * FROM `recipe_breakfast`";
$qrResult  = mysqli_query($db, $qr);
$count = mysqli_num_rows($qrResult);

if($count > 0)
{
    while($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qrResult)) 
    {
                $result[] = $data;
        }
    $response = array('msg' => 'Success','details' => $result);
}
else
{
    $response = array('msg' => 'No details found');
}

@mysqli_close($db);

/* Output header */
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

Comment: Add this
`header( 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );`

Comment: still facing the same issue

Comment: {"msg":"Success","details":[{"id":"3","recipe_name":"????? ????","time_required":"?","ingredients":"? ??? ??? ????. Like this i am getting response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a charset issue.

In your code, after this line:

```
include_once('config_db.php');
```

Add this:

```
mysqli_query($db, 'set names utf8mb4');
```

If somehow your database doesn't support `utf8mb4`, use this instead:

```
mysqli_query($db, 'set names utf8');
```

This should solve the problem.

If it doesn't, you also have an issue in your table.
The solution is to set the collation of every `varchar` or `text` column to
`utf8mb4_general_ci`.
This means that you have to redo the data entry.

Comment: thanks... getting response in the language i want to.